# How to solve the form is undefined , Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I have two routes inside my application, if i want to access the second one i got this error:

`UndefinedError: 'register_form' is undefined`

The **register_form** is for the first route, here is the **first route**:

```
@abonent_route.route('/')
@abonent_route.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():

    register_form = RegistrationForm()
    return render_template('index.html', register_form=register_form)
```

This is the **second route**:

```
@client_route.route('/client/')
@client_route.route('/client/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form_login = ClientLogin()
    return render_template('index.html', form_login=form_login)
```

Also I've initialized the routes inside my **create_app** function as following:

```
from .abonent import abonent_route
app.register_blueprint(abonent_route)

from .client import client_route
app.register_blueprint(client_route)
```

Now the problem is if i replaced the **client route** step up so to be above the **abonent route** and if i open **abonent route**, i got the same error but a little bit different:

`UndefinedError: 'form_login' is undefined`

This time, the **form_login is undefined**, also if i again moved the abonent back again to it place and if i want to visit the **client route**, i got the first error which is **register_form undefined** .

Please any help would be appreciated .

**Edit: Add some codes**

`Client main route`:

```
@client_route.route('/client/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form_login = ClientLogin()
    if request.method == 'GET' and request.args.get('next'):
        session['next'] = request.args.get('next')

    if form_login.validate_on_submit():
        user = Client.query.filter_by(
            tele = form_login.telephone.data
        ).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, form_login.password.data):
                session['client_logged_in'] = user.name
                session['client_family'] = user.family
                session['client_image'] = user.image
                session['client_phone'] = user.tele
                if 'next' in session:
                    next = session.get('next')
                    session.pop('next')
                    return redirect(next)
                else:
                    flash('Привет, {}'.format(user.name), 'success')
                    return redirect(url_for('client.profile'))
            else:
                flash('Неверные учетные данные.', 'danger')
                return redirect(url_for('client.index'))
        else:
            flash('Неверные учетные данные.', 'danger')
            return redirect(url_for('client.index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form_login=form_login)
```

`Abonent main route`:

```
@abonent_route.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    register_form = RegistrationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if register_form.is_submitted():
            if not register_form.terms_agree.data:
                flash('Вы должны согласиться с нашим договором и со всеми его пунктами.', 'danger')
                return redirect(url_for("abonent.index"))
            if register_form.master_salon.data or register_form.master_cto.data or register_form.master_company.data == True:
                user = User()
                user.name = register_form.name.data
                user.family = register_form.family.data
                user.bio = register_form.biography.data
                if User.query.filter_by(tele=register_form.telephone.data).first():
                    flash('Этот номер: {} уже использован.'.format(register_form.telephone.data), "warning")
                    return redirect(url_for('abonent.index'))
                else:
                    user.tele = register_form.telephone.data
                user.set_password(register_form.password.data)
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('abonent.confirm', phone=phone))
return render_template('index.html', register_form=register_form)
```

Here is a link to where full error shows, this one is raises if the **client route** is under **abonent route** in `__init__.py` file:

[Click to open](https://pastebin.com/EQ77zstu)

Another thing that i forgot to mention is, if tried to open for example `/client/registration`, it opens without any error, the error raises if i wanted to access `/client` which is the index page for `client`

Comment: Why do u have redundant routing? only one is enough since both route the same path and request, and Are u importing `RegistrationForm` and `ClientLogin` into your file? and at what point is this error raised up?, may be you should post full error to trace it back to right point?

Comment: The error raises if i replaced one of these routes above the other inside my **create_app function** and tried to access it , so if the **abonent** was above if i want to open **/client/** an error appears that says : **register_form undefined**, and vice versa for client the other error appears that says : **form_login undefined** .

Comment: Yes, i importing the **RegisterForm** in my **abonent views.py** but not **ClientLogin**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is a couple of redundant block info in your code.

```
@abonent_route.route('/')
@abonent_route.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

You don't need twice to declare this route. The bottom line will be enough.

> Also I've initialized the routes inside my create_app function as
> following:

It is not declaring route. It's a blueprint. It's like big part of your project.
I can have many routes in your blueprint.
You don't need declare one blueprint for one route.

For a more detailed answer, please provide a more detailed source code of your application.

Take a look:
http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/blueprints.html and
[DO docs](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications)

Comment: Hi @Vladimir , thanks for your interest, i already deleted the unwanted routes but without avail , same error showing every time, and i can provide code but which one you interest in ?

Comment: I saw the blueprint documents, but the app that am making is really huge, i have tell now 4 routes each one in a separated folder with their views , forms, templates, statics and models, i don't see any other different from my app structure i believe its almost the same structure , the error is somewhere that i can't find or debug it !!!

Comment: I'am accessing the `/client/` route, why am getting an error with a junk of info's that belongs to `/abonent/` route !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I must be kidding with myself Hahahaha, i solved the problem.

Inside `__init__.py` file in my client folder i configured the route as following:

```
from flask import Blueprint

client_route = Blueprint(
    'client',
    __name__,
    template_folder='templates/client',
    static_folder='../static'
)

from . import views
```

As you can see here, **index.html** must be inside client folder, when i rendered **index.html** inside my views i forgot to add client/ before index.html here :

`return render_template('client/index.html', form_login=form_login)`

It was looking in my main app templates folder where another index.html is saved .

Now everything is working very well:) , thank you all guys for your interests .